# Register a ad v2 endpoint and add sso sign in?

Tags: azure-active-directory

Since v2 endpoint webapi needed to be standalone with the client has to be the same client id, we have a vendor app only works under Saml token, in v1 we would simply do a sso app, but how 
To achieve this in v2 so the authenticated calls from th vendor app could make to the secured webapi

Comment: Thanks so basically opened is only option then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK ,you can't implement SAML SSO with v2.0 endpoint .From [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-limitations#restrictions-on-protocols) :

> > The v2.0 endpoint does not support SAML or WS-Federation; it only supports Open ID Connect and OAuth 2.0.